# Convert css box shadow with inset to svg shadow?

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way to convert a given css `box-shadow` with `inset` to svg shadow?

For example, I have this box-shadow:

```
box-shadow: inset -1px -2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50),
    inset 1px 1px 4px rgba(255, 22, 64, 0.16);
}
```

I understand that to set the shadow of svg you would have to use drop-shadow:

```
filter: drop-shadow(-1px -2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50));
```

This of course doesn't look the same because it's missing the inset (and the second inset)
Is there a way to convert that box shadow, without creating a new one from scratch?

Comment: All you need to know: [Adding Shadows to SVG...](https://css-tricks.com/adding-shadows-to-svg-icons-with-css-and-svg-filters/), including *inset*.

Comment: @RenevanderLende That article handles `drop-shadow()`, not `box-shadow()`. To implement the `spread-radius` value, you need the [`feMorphology`](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#feMorphologyElement) filter primitive, but that is only an approximation: it does not support following a border radius and might look seriously botched if applied to anything but a rectangle.